# How to right set height of NSTableCellView with NSTextField?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nstablecolumn

Greets!

I have a View-based NSTableView with Custom View as a cell (NSTableCellView class).
There is NSTextField inside custom cell.

I need to display 3 lines of text inside NSTextField and after clicking on cell content must grow up to fit full text.
So, I need to increment height of NSTextField and height of NSCTableCellView by click in other words.

Alghoritm is:

1. Handle click on NSTableCellView
2. Calculate new sizes of NSTextField and NSTableCellView
3. SetFrameSize to NSTextField through IBOutlet
4. Store new NSTableCellView height value in class and invoke function "RowHeightChanged" through Notification Center
5. Set new row height from class value

This is a code snippet: (i erased some unusefull things)

TickCellTableView:

```
    @implementation TickCellTableView

    // Other Constants
    @synthesize textFieldInitHeight = _textFieldInitHeight;
    @synthesize rowHeight           = _rowHeight;
    @synthesize rowIndex            = _rowIndex;

    - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

        if (![self.superview isKindOfClass:[NSTableCellView class]])
            [super mouseDown:theEvent];


        CGFloat TextFieldFitHeight = [self getHeightForStringDrawing: self.textField.stringValue
                                                          withFont:[self.textField font]
                                                      forTextWidth:[self.textField frame].size.width + 10.0];

        if ([self.textField frame].size.height < TextFieldFitHeight)
        {
            NSSize size = [self.textField frame].size;
            size.height = TextFieldFitHeight;

            [self.textField setFrameSize:size];        

            self.rowHeight = [self frame].size.height + (TextFieldFitHeight - _textFieldInitHeight);

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RowHeightChanged"


                                                                   object:self.rowIndex];
            }
        }
@end
```

NSTableView Delegate:

```
@implementation DisplayTicksView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(RowHeightChanged:)
                                                 name: @"RowHeightChanged"
                                               object:nil];    
 }

-(void)RowHeightChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{        
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:[notification.object integerValue]];

    [tableView noteHeightOfRowsWithIndexesChanged:indexSet];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
{
    return [ticksArray count];
}


@end
```

The problem is when i clicked on the NSTextField it's frame grow up just for the second and return to init size, after that starts animation to set property height of cell.
In result - Cell height is up, but NSTextField none. I tried to disable animation - no result. How can i fix that?

Appologise my English :)

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm having the same issue! :)